# How to install new fonts for the terminal?

Tags: command-line, fonts

I installed a new font and I can use it anywhere except the terminal. I tried to go to the Terminal's preferences, but my font is not available. I can use it via `gnome-tweaks` -> Fonts. But in terminal the font just does not show up.

I want to use it in the terminal, so what can I do?

The font is monospace, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Is it a monospace font? Please give specifics about that particular font. And the version of your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @FedKad Edited.

Comment: Where in the terminal preferences do you expect the font to show up?

Comment: @vanadium Preferences -> Profile -> Text

Comment: The font isn't literally called "monospace" is it? That name is usually used as an alias for the default monospace font; it shouldn't be used as the name of an actual font.

Comment: Not a lot we can help. You may have installed the font incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will not show ALL the newly installed fonts in the terminal because the terminal is designed to use **monospaced fonts**. Fonts that have letters too close to each other may look weird. Some fonts do not offer proper clarity between the alphabet O and the number 0. Similarly, you may face issues in differentiating the lowercase l and i.